# Too many active IP Connections

Tags: ubuntu, connection, router

I have a Linksys WRT54GS v7 with a dd-wrt (micro) installed on.
When I try to view `Active IP Connections`, I see too many connection there.
Interestingly, there are about 120 connections that originate from my computer. At that time, I have no download programming running, (no torrent). I only have an instance of Chrome, Eclipse, Skype, Empathy running.
How come my apps consume such a large amount of connections?
I'm running Ubuntu 9.10.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would imagine that if you checked most of those connections will be on port 80 and in a `TIME_WAIT` state.

> TIME_WAIT is a state
>   where connections could conceivably be re-used without
>   making a new TCP
>   between servers, so it can help reduce load.

So basically your router is saving a tcp socket for later use to the same site.

Answer (score 0):

The router only saves a connection for a few minutes at most. The source might more possibly coming from skype. Skype is based on P2P technology to provide high quality calls. But that means it has to keep alot of connections up at the same time.

The problem arises when you have a lot of skype clients going through the same router, a router can only manage a fixed amount of connections. If you exceed that limit, it will block additional connections untill previous ones timeout.